# Unable to update confluence page with content from an HTML file using curl

Tags: html, json, curl, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to update a Confluence page with some HTML content. I have this HTML content in a different file named `Output.html` in the same location. I cannot directly copy & paste that HTML content to this script, as it is a huge amount of data, and also I need to execute this script dynamically.

```
curl -u user:pass -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"id":"2196","type":"page","title":"Main page","space":{"key":"AB"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p> Text </p>","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":2}}' https://Client.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/2196 | python -mjson.tool
```

For example, my HTML file content is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Page Title</title> </head> <body>  <h1>My First Heading</h1> <p>My first paragraph.</p>  </body> </html>
```

I need this to be updated on my Confluence page as HTML content, which needs to fetched directy from the HTML file to the script `"value":"<p> Text </p>"`

When I manually copy sample HTML content to this `value` space, the page successfully shows the HTML content.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: Yes, I know that.  I can even see where you piped your JSON to Python's `json.tool`.  So?  I ask again:  What does this --- your question and the problem it describes --- have to do with Python?

Comment: Hi Kevin, This is the method i've been using so far to update the confluence pages from my RHEL servers where Python is installed. 

Just to get the output in a well formatted way.  Thats it!

Any suggestions on my question ?. I'm stuck with that.

Comment: Since your question has nothing to do with Python --- meaning no amount of Python knowledge will help you solve it --- I have removed the [python] tag.

Comment: That is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this thing worked using Python and it's request module. See code below,

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://Client.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/87440'
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Accept': "application/json"}
f = open("file.html", "r")
html = f.read()
data={}
data['id'] = "87440"
data['type']="page"
data['title']="Data Page"
data['space']={"key":"AB"}
data['body'] = {"storage":{"representation":"storage"}}
data['version']={"number":4}
print data
data['body']['storage']['value'] = html
print data
res = requests.put(url, json=data, auth=('Username', 'Password'))

print (res.status_code)
print (res.raise_for_status())
```

Feel free to ask if you have got any doubt.